# Refresh view model in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, thread-safety

I have a collection of structs.

```
typedef struct _myStruct
{
  int item1;
  int item2;
  int item3;
  .
  .
  .
}
```

In my main window I have created columns item1, item2 item3...

```
QStandardItemModel *model = new QStandardItemModel();
model->setHorizontalHeaderItem(0, new QStandardItem(QString("Item1")));
model->setHorizontalHeaderItem(1, new QStandardItem(QString("Item2")));
.
.
.
```

And fill model rows in cycle.

The main collection is changed by callbacks and then I create a new `QStandartItemModel` and do the same thing.

```
QStandardItemModel *model2 = new QStandardItemModel();
.
.
.
.
```

After I set `model = model2;` and this works in the background every x seconds.

Is this the best way? How can I update model repeatedly on background?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend making a subclass for QStandardItemModel.

In its constructor it would take a pointer to the main collection, which it could use to fill its rows. It would also connect some signals from the main collection to tell when it has changed.

Say your main collection has an "itemRemoved" signal. You would connect it to an "onItemRemoved" slot, where you would locate and delete the corresponding row in your QStandardItemModel subclass.

This way, you don't need to poll every X seconds; the view model changes as soon as your "real" model changes.